# Laravel 5 relationship using a 'JSON' column

Tags: json, database, laravel-5, eloquent, php-7

Is it possible to use Eloquent to create a relationship in Laravel 5 where the foreign key exists in a field in a `JSON` column?

If it is, how so?

Example:
I have a table called `chats` with a `participantIds` column, of a `JSON` datatype. The `JSON` format of the data looks like this:

```
{"creator": "1", "recipient": "2"}
```

I want to join the `users` table using those fields to get the participants of the Chats.
How do I do that?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Laravel has no native support for JSON relationships.

I created a package for this: https://github.com/staudenmeir/eloquent-json-relations

You can use it like this:

```php
class Chat extends Model
{
    use \Staudenmeir\EloquentJsonRelations\HasJsonRelationships;

    protected $casts = [
       'participantIds' => 'json',
    ];

    public function creator()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class, 'participantIds->creator');
    }

    public function recipient()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class, 'participantIds->recipient');
    }
}

class User extends Model
{
    use \Staudenmeir\EloquentJsonRelations\HasJsonRelationships;

    public function createdChats()
    {
       return $this->hasMany(Chat::class, 'participantIds->creator');
    }

    public function receivedChats()
    {
       return $this->hasMany(Chat::class, 'participantIds->recipient');
    }
}
```

Comment: I struggled whole day to use such nice package. But I am getting the following error: require php ^7.2.5 || ^8.0 -> your php version (7.2; overridden via config.platform, actual: 7.2.5) does not satisfy that requirement.