# How to put this key from json like a foreign key in relation?

Tags: json, laravel, eloquent

This is a structure of my json, and the field - type is a foreign key, how can I get it like foreign key, I can not change structure of json. `$this->hasMany(Animals::class,'animals->type','id')` This code does not work

```
{
   "animals": [
                {
                   "unique": 1, 
                   "type": [
                         2341
                       ]
                }
              ]
}
```

Comment: you have a json field in this table?

Comment: @lagbox yes, column pets

Comment: @JitendraYadav it does not work too

Comment: I thought that it is not stored in database. Now can you tell me that whether it would be multiple objects in `animal` and there would be multiple `type`s inside each object.

Comment: @JitendraYadav it must be multiple objects but type is only one but like array.

Comment: Laravel Does not support relationship with json column perhaps you can refer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53878743/laravel-5-relationship-using-a-json-column for custom solution